# How to process in JavaScript based on Shop ID passed as part of io.to() in Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my JS client I am using two input fields: one will have the text *message* and other is *shopID (eg: Shop-123-test)*. If the Shop ID passed from JS client is same as ID passed in io.to(shopID) then I should process the message sent in emit.

Node js Socket IO part: 
io.to(shopID + "-test").emit("message", data);

In the below Java Script code I am not sure where to pass/check the Shop ID.

```
socket.on(message, function(data)
{        
    console.log(data);
    processMessage(data);
});
```

Can some one please help me to resolve this?

Comment: May i know when is this message is emitted from the back-end? and are you using a a frontend framework?